# Pandas Query astype(str)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column that usually has numbers only. On occasion, it will have text values, which means it will be of type `object` instead `int64`.

Instead of doing `ColumnA == "100" & ColumnA == 100`, I am trying to perform a query that will compare the value to the string value of an integer:

```
df.query('ColumnA.astype(str) == "100"))
```

But this gives me a `KeyError` saying the `str` key does not exist.

Is there a way to use `astype` within a pandas query?

Comment: How about using boolean indexing?

Comment: you don't need `query` for such case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest My query is actually more complex and it is easier to use `.query()` however I am having problem with the column being cast as int or text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't need [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) in this kind of *usecases*, you should enclose `str` with *quotes* :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA": ["100", 200, "300", 400, 100, "500"]})

out = df.query('ColumnA.astype("str") == "100"')
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  ColumnA
0     100
4     100
```